# ¿Como manipular JSON en Javascript obtenido desde PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy buscando la manera de poder manipular datos `JSON` obtenidos desde `PHP`.

Desde un archivo `html` y utilizando `Ajax`, obtengo los datos de un formulario que al recibir cualquier tipo de cambio, envio a sus valores a un `Controlador` en `PHP`   y este envia sus valores a un `Modelo`, del `Modelo` obtengo un `JSON` utlizando la función `json_encode`, luego, en el *success* del `Ajax` quisiera poder manipular los datos obtenidos pero no encuentro una manera.

Archivo `Javascript:`

```
$(".indicadores").change(function(){
    var opcion = $("#lista").val();
    var fecha = $("#primeraFecha").val();
    var datos = new FormData();
    // console.log("año anterior: ", yearAnterior);
    datos.append("opcion", opcion); 
    datos.append("fecha", fecha);

        $.ajax({
            url: "views/modules/ajax.php",
            method:"POST",
            data: datos,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(respuesta){
                console.log(respuesta)
            }
        });
});
```

`Modelo` en PHP:

```
<?php 
require("conexion.php");

class Datos extends conexion
{
    public static function indicadoresModel($datosModel)
    {


            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare($consulta);

            $stmt->bindParam(":fecha", $datosModel['fecha'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();

            return json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

            $stmt->closeCursor();

    }
}
```

Resultado de `console.log(respuesta):`

```
[{"BANCO":"100%BANCO (BU)","ACTIVOS_LIQUIDOS":"543455343","ACTIVOS_RENTABLES":"534354","PASIVOS_EXIGIBLES":"789879"....
```

Me gustaria saber como poder obtener cada campo del `JSON`, por ejemplo "Banco".

Comment: Deberías agregar el resultado de `console.log(respuesta)` a la pregunta y sobre todo de que manera quieres manipular esos datos.

Comment: @Emeeus listo, ya agregue el resultado y lo que quiero lograr

Comment: en el Ajax agrega el `dataType: "json"` para que lo devuelva como una variable de tipo json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tienes es un Array de objetos, si quieres obtener la propiedad BANCO de cada objeto del array, estas serían algunas opciones (**no todas**), dependiendo de que quieras hacer con esos datos puede ser mas útil una o la otra.

```js
const respuesta = [{"BANCO":"100%BANCO (BU)","ACTIVOS_LIQUIDOS":"543455343","ACTIVOS_RENTABLES":"534354","PASIVOS_EXIGIBLES":"789879"},{"BANCO":"90%BANCO (BU)","ACTIVOS_LIQUIDOS":"543455343","ACTIVOS_RENTABLES":"534354","PASIVOS_EXIGIBLES":"789879"}];

//Primer elemento
console.log(respuesta[0].BANCO);

//Todos los elementos de a uno
respuesta.forEach(e => console.log(e.BANCO));

//Un nuevo array solo con los valores que quieras 
const bancos = respuesta.map(e => e.BANCO);

console.log(bancos);
```

Cualquier cosa de estas que implementes tiene que estar siempre dentro del callback

```
success: function(respuesta){
                //aqui
            }
```

Comment: Intente realizar lo siguiente pero no funciona ninguno de los casos, use `typeof` para verificar que sea un objeto, y si, lo es

Comment: Que significa "no funciona"? arroja algún error? Si la salida que pusiste en la pregunta es idéntica a lo que tienes realmente, tiene que funcionar si o si, mientras lo pongas en el callback.

Answer (score 2):

Mi solución fue la siguiente.

1. En `$.ajax` implementé `dataType: "json"`, eso significa que la solicitud espera una `json` de respuesta.
2. Apliqué un `console.log(typeof respuesta)` dentro del `success` de Ajax, para verificar si realmente era un objeto lo que obtenía.
3. Para poder manipular dichos objetos, lo hice de la siguiente manera, primero accediendo a la posición y luego al campo, ya que si trato de ir directamente al campo `(respuesta.banco)` me sale un error.

Así quedo el código:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "views/modules/ajax.php",
            method:"POST",
            data: datos,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType:'JSON',
            success: function(respuesta){
                    console.log(respuesta[0].BANCO);
            }
        });
```